# How could one "empirically" calculate density of states?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, density-of-states

I've been studying statistical mechanics and recently came across an interesting optional challenge.

The [Einstein model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_solid) and the [Debye model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_model) of solids are common ways of describing the heat capacities of solids. Generally, the Debye model works better at low temperatures and the Einstein model works better at high temperatures. A density of states function can be used to calculate and plot heat capacities.

**The Challenge**

I have to assume any solid, a cube of solid ice, or a cube of solid metal. Then, using any programming language (I'm working with Python), I have to empirically calculate its density of states, then plot heat capacities based on the data versus a Debye model and an Einstein model of the same solid.

I'm not asking for the code. Instead, what does it mean to "empirically" determine a density of states? Since this is all in code, it's not like I have a physical sample of my solid to work with. This is undergraduate level, so we shouldn't worry about things such as the molecular structure of the solids.

This is just a personal project to "waste" time on during the holidays. Thank you for your contribution! I hope to have interesting conversations.

Answer (score 1):

Empirical means measured in reality. The only empirical data you can get from a computer process is empirical data about the computer process itself.

Perhaps your instructor wants you to identify the measureable parameters, code a simple function that takes those inputs, then do the actual measurements for a variety of household objects? I would request clarification.

Comment: Okay, I should clarify. Yes, I believe what you are saying is the point of this exercise. Put values of DOS in, and get a function out of the data. Then derive heat capacity from the function and compare it to the Debye model and the Einstein model.

Now, the question is how could you "measure" DOS, because as far as I've been taught, I can only come up with it mathematically.

Comment: Other way around. Measure the volumetric heat capacity, temperature, and volume; output the density of states predicted by the model.